# Checking in and out files within branches without moving to the Master Branch

Tags: git, git-branch, branching-and-merging

Assume that I have 4 branches

```
Master Branch

Branch 1

Branch 2

Branch 3
```

I am currently in Branch 3 and I want to get all the files from Branch 2 to Branch 3 without committing the files to Master branch.
Is that possible?

Comment: what do your branches look like?

Comment: Do you mean you want to get all the *commits* of branch 2 to branch 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Option 1 - Merge branch2 into branch3

It will record the merging history in your branch3.

```
`git checkout <branch 3>
 git merge <branch 2>`
```

- Option 2 - Fetch the files you want into branch3

  `git checkout <branch 3>
  git checkout <branch> -- path/to/files`

Answer (score 2):

You could either:

- merge branch2 to branch3

  ```
   git checkout branch3
   git merge branch2
  ```
- or, depending on what you need, force branch3 to become branch2

  ```
  git checkout branch2
  git branch -f branch3 branch2
  git checkout branch3
  ```

(that would replace the history of branch3 by the one of branch2)

In both cases, commits on master would be unchanged.

Comment: Thank you. Since the above answer has the explanation with the code, Ill mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: @HarshaW Which option did you choose? merge, or checkout?